# Extract Distinct Record in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, duplicates

I am writing the SSIS package to import the data from *.csv files to the SQL 2008 DB.  The problem is that one of the file contains the duplicate records in the csv file and I want to extract only the distinct values from that source.  Please see the image below.

### [image: Duplicate]

Unfortunately, the generated files are not under my control and it is owned by the third party and I could not change the way they generated.

I did use the LookUp Component.  But it only checks the existing data against the incoming data.  It does not check the duplicate records in the incoming data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how serious you want to get about the duplicates. Do you need a record of what was duplicated or is it enough to just get rid of them? Sort component will get rid of dups on the sort field. However, the dups may have different data in the other fields and then you want a differnt strategy. Usually I load all to staging tables and clean up from there. I send the dupes removed to an exception table (we have to answer a lot of questions from our customers about why things don't match what they sent) and I often use a set of business rules (and use either an execute SQl or data flow tasks to enforce the rules) to determine which one to pick if there are duplicates in one area but not another (say two business addresses when we can only store 1). I also make sure the client is aware of how we determine which of the two to pick.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the sort component gives an option to remove duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2):

Use SORT tool for that from Toolbox, then click on it. You will get all available input columns.
Check the column and change sortType direction and then check "remove rows with duplicate sort value".

Answer (score 0):

Bring in the data from the csv file the way it is, then dedup it after it's loaded.
It'll be easier to debug, too.

Answer (score 0):

I used Aggregate Component and Group By both QualificationID and UnitID.  If you want, you can also use Sort Component too.  Perhaps, my information might help others.

Comment: Please say exactly how you did this. In particular, did you group by both columns and just use the grouped columns as output columns? Were there no other columns from the source that you cared about?